# How to make the newly added tab active in angular2?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have used the below mentioned plunker for creating dynamic tabs. I wanted to know how to make the newly added tab active in the following plunker code.

Comment: plunker used is http://plnkr.co/edit/kQS0f9ERUOKRToA1bEXq?p=preview

Comment: Any suggestions please.